# Python. GZIP decompression error:Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, gzip

I am trying to get readable data from API. Instead all i get is this set of characters and an error when trying to decypher it.

API response:

```
{"filters":{"search":null},"s":"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","status":true,"app_version":"90e096f485e0d60f8d178dd68c969046"}
```

Response-Header

```
{content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
date: Sun, 29 Jul 2018 05:58:31 GMT
server: nginx/1.13.8
set-cookie: AWSALB=SizCXt0Efa9j8m2g49t634wx4uYAvyGE+Nv38eijmZ6IuFbQJfEpSQ6M7hKVdK/eNK0s0IRWhZslAeMYTb6ZqFWJnP4XGb2gh6jyVVyCwl6ACdmW/zaOhvQOsUCO; Expires=Sun, 05 Aug 2018 05:58:30 GMT; Path=/
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Cookie
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN}
```

When i try to decompress this json I am getting the following error.

```
zlib.decompress(response.text, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0f203c63245d> in <module>()
----> 1 zlib.decompress(response.text, zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)

error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Comment: Looks like the data is not gzip compressed, but rather uuencoded or something.

Comment: @John Zwinck is there a way to find out correct encoding?

Comment: Try to decode it.  I think the long string starting with TQQI and ending with == is uuencoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `TQQ...` and `Siz...` strings are Base-64 encoded. The decoded results are not gzip or zlib streams. They have a flat distribution of byte values, indicating that they are compressed, encrypted, or both.

Comment: then why bother with protection of the web data from scraping if can be merely compressed and ecnrypted like here? So 3d party cant read it properly.